# getting logged in username in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, authentication

I tried to follow brad adams tutorial on this link for authentication in silverlight

[Click here to brad adams tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/13/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-3-authentication.aspx)

anyhoo I need to get the logged in username to write down into my database for audit trail purposes, 
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can get the username via the HttpContext

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`